# Auto-upload tool

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

i created an automatic upload tool, working great (most of the time). As i want to improve the code i have several questions:
1)Is it possible to make the iexplorer progress some kind of smoother? I don't like it that people can see the "sendkeys" actions. Is there a possibilty running the progress in the background/ lay a picture over the grocess? In addition to that is there a posibillity to block the user's input for some seconds? I know the opportunity of the blockinput command, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
2) Is it possible to close the browsers site (only the one, which was opened for the upload!) and return to excel?

Thanks in advance !

```
Sub speichern_unter()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim str_pfad As String
str_pfad = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\" 'Die Datei wird auf den Desktop gespeichert
Rem MsgBox str_pfad
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs str_pfad & ActiveSheet.Range("m1").Value & ".xlsm" 'Diese Zelle gibt den Tabellennamen vor

'Zur Sicherheit wird eine zusätzliche Backup-Datei an eine E-Mail verschickt (optional)
MsgBox "Eine Backup-Datei wird erstellt und per Mail verschickt. Bitte bestätigen Sie im nachfolgenden Fenster mit 'erteilen'", , "OK"
ActiveWorkbook.SendMail "###@###.de", "###Dateiname###"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Ab hier beginnt der Upload-Vorgang
MsgBox "Die Datei wird nun ins ### geladen. Dies kann einige Sekunden dauern! Bitte beachten Sie, dass Sie hierfür im ### eingeloggt sein müssen!", , "OK"
MsgBox "Berühren Sie während des Vorganges nicht die Maus oder Tastatur! (Dauer ca. 30 Sekunden)", , "OK"
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'appIE.Visible = False
appIE.navigate "https://###/docs/DOC-257603/upload#" 'Link zur "Bearbeiten" Seite im TSN
While appIE.Busy
        DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
SendKeys "+{TAB}", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "Desktop/"
SendKeys "{Enter}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
SendKeys "{TAB}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "###Dateiname###.xlsm"
SendKeys "{ENTER}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))
'Nachfolgender Ausdruck löscht den bisherigen Namen aus dem Textfeld
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
SendKeys "{DEL}", True
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
SendKeys "###Dateiname###", True 'Hier wird der spätere Name der Datei definiert
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
SendKeys "{ENTER}"

MsgBox "Die Datei wurde ergfolgreich hochgeladen", , "OK"

End Sub
```

Comment: Consider posting this on the [Code Review forum](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Welcome to SO - there are already answers to most of your questions - have you tried searching the site or using Google? Maybe try asking just 1 question that you need help with?